# How to get results from all Tensorflow's while_loop() iterations as a list of not specified length?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I want to get results from all `while_loop()` iterations, so that `tf.shape(result) == [batch_size, input_length]`.

`batch_size` and `input_length` may differ from mini-batch to mini-batch, so I evaluate their shapes dynamically.

I created this code:

```
batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]
input_length = tf.shape(x)[1]

result = []
lstm = BasicLSTMCell(hidden_units)
cell = MultiRNNCell([lstm])

init_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)

def body(i, x, result, state):
    h, state = cell(x[:, i, :], state)
    result.append(h)
    i += 1

    return i, x, result, state

    def cond(i, *_):
        return tf.less(i, input_length - 1)

    _, _, result, state = tf.while_loop(cond, body, (i, x, result, init_state))
```

But Tensorflow implicitly `flatten()` all `loop_vars` I passed to it, so after 2 iterations my `while_loop()` input has size_of 4 but output has size_of 5 (due to 2 elements in the `result` variables).

I tried to use `shape_invatiants` but it doesn't work, probably due to usage of regular Python list. But still - I can't provide the exact size of that list (and if I will - it would be a hack) - because it matches number of iterations and this is the key feature which stands behind usage of `while_loop()` at all - to stop dynamically!

I don't need to add that it works fine if I just reassign result like this instead of append `h` to the `result` list:

```
h, state = cell(x[:, i, :], state)
result = h
```

So it seems to me a bit unreasonable- **in most cases `while_loop()` is just an acumulator, not iterator! But if you want to use it as the iterator - it's almost defend itself from allowing you do that..**

Can anyone know how to deal with it? I would be extremely grateful.

I'm using Tensorflow 1.5

**EDIT:**

From the line 749 of [rnn.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py#L747) in TF github library I understand that at least `batch` or `input_length` must be constant, but both can't be `None`

So - if you want to compute RNN dynamicaly - you should provide at least `max_input_length` param, for results, but your loop will be stopped after `batch_size` (when you reshape input `x` to `[input_length, batch_size, vocab_size]`. Is that correct?

Comment: Check out the function `tf.keras.backend.rnn` defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py). Make use of `TensorArray` to store intermediate values in the while loop, then use the `stack()` function for each element to convert to a stacked `Tensor`